# Where is the battery animation called from when wall charger connected to phone (OFF)?

Tags: android, batterymanager

I have Moto E (Rooted) which turn on when connected with USB via Laptop but not when connected to Wall charger instead it shows Battery animation. I got to know that battery animation is at `framework-res.apk.`

Now I want to know from where it is called so that i can change it as required.

Comment: have you find the answer for this??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294258/auto-boot-when-wall-charger-is-plugged?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Through my experience with this try the following files:

```
  /system/bin/lpm
  /system/bin/lpmkey
```

Or the like.

Comment: final try: anything with "lpm" in the title

Comment: (lpm_levels),(qcom,lpm-levels.65)