# Scheduled Power Off and On feature

Tags: android, su

I have 2 phones- Karbonn and Micromax both has in-built feature- Scheduled power OFF and ON in setting where user can specify time for both events. I want this functionality on my Motorola too so that i can turn ON my phone whenever i want . Is there any library or api available for this purpose.I have rooted my phone.
Any Idea will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, `Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN` or `Intent.ACTION_REBOOT` ... which is **fortunately** reserverd for system apps

Comment: i have root phone and able to shutdown but i want to turn ON the phone automatically

Comment: then you have to press power button ... just think, if power is OFF then the OS is not running ...

Comment: but i have 2 phones which have this feature and working great. you can search that "Scheduled Power off and On.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want this functionality on my Motorola too so that i can turn ON my phone whenever i want .

That is unlikely to be possible. The "scheduled power on" feature that you describe requires specialized hardware. On most Android devices, OFF means OFF.

If you wish to find out if your Motorola device supports "scheduled power on", please contact Motorola.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have another question 
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294258/auto-boot-when-wall-charger-is-plugged)
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583245/where-is-the-battery-animation-called-from-when-wall-charger-connected-to-phone)