# Boot Android device once charging - how to do it, how to watch what programs run

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, boot

We are trying to set up an Android 4.4.2 device to boot once it is plugged in to a power source. The device is a POSH Titan HD E500.

We've come across different ways that each manufacturer handles the booting (see links at the end of this question). The one consistent trend is that people try to seat their code alongside the indicator that comes up to show you battery percentage during charging. It seems like a good way to proceed is to replace the contents of that battery indicator program with something like **/system/bin/reboot**.

My question is: does anyone know a good way to find which program is getting called when that battery indicator comes up on a new phone? The phone will be off at the time, but the device will also be rooted in case that helps.

Any advice would be tremendously appreciated!

some of the links we've found for other manufacturers:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39899/auto-boot-when-charger-connected-for-htc-magic (HTC),
[Auto boot when wall charger is plugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294258/auto-boot-when-wall-charger-is-plugged) (Moto-E),
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1187631 (Samsung)

Comment: Have you found a soltion for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into `init.rc`. There is a part under `on charger` that is executed when charging. Further information here: https://appdictive.dk/blog/android/how-to/2017/04/20/disabeling_offline_charge_on_android/